# how to make an "employee" "user" by default in odoo 9

Tags: odoo-9

I have a module which will not inherit from another one it will be for sports club

players and trainers will have access rights to use the system and my question as follows:

1- which is better, create new model from scratch or inherit from partners, employee, contact or users

2- if I create new model or inherit from another model which is not users how to make any player a user by default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will probably have to create a partner for your user anyways. My thought is that you may want to make your players partners. You can override the view and remove the elements that are not player oriented or hide them if the `is_player` flag is true. (You may want to add a new `is_player` boolean). You can use the `is_player` boolean to define when to display the player view or a generic contact view.

Personally I would use partner and users as so much of Odoo's security and structures are already built around these models.

If your player inherits partner you can override the create() method and within it simply create a user after you have created your contact.

```
@api.model
@api.returns('self', lambda rec: rec.id)
def create(self, vals):
    vals['notify_email'] = 'always'
    rec = super(Partner, self).create(vals)
    v = {
         'active': True,
         'login': rec.email,
         'company_id': 1,
         'partner_id': rec.id,
         'create_uid': 1,
         'write_uid': 1,
         'display_groups_suggestions': False,
         'share': False
    }
    user_id = self.env['res.users'].sudo().create(v)

    return rec
```

The above example creates a user with a bunch of values you will probably want to change to be more appropriate for your needs. After you create the user you will want to send a password reset.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer I think it will do the trick, please to vote up my question as someone has voted it done and decrease my points.
I thought that creating a partner will create a user automatically but will I need to update "user_id" field in "res.partner" table?

Comment: but since "res.users" are inherited from "res.partner" why not to inherit from "res.users"?

Comment: It is really up to you. If you inherit partner you can use the partner view which I think is more appropriate than the the user view for conveying mostly contact information. I like restricting access to the user specific components of res_users to administrators. And provide limited access to it through the partner model. The right way really depends on how you want your users to interact with the models and views. Both methods have pros and cons. I have also had to deal with complications using my suggested method. Others may argue differently however I dont know if there is a perfect answer

Comment: when I tried your function to create a user I got this error: 
You cannot create a new user from here.
To create new user please go to configuration panel.

Comment: I have seen this error before. I think it is misleading. I think it often is related to the data that you use to create it. Are you specifying the required fields and using sudo()?

Comment: I will update my script. I left some components out because I am not sure if it is really the best way to do it or not. But I will update and you can see if it works for you.

Comment: I changed rec.email to rec.name and it worked, thanks :)

Comment: I encountered the exact error you did when I first tried to create a user from a method on my partner model. I initially thought it was not possible to create a user from the partner model (because that is what the error says). I tried a bunch of complicated sql to create the user manually (it was crazy ugly) then somewhere I saw someone saying you could do it the way you see above. I use it everyday. So I think there is just a field left out that Odoo requires.